# Php version overridden by "config.platform.php"

Tags: magento, composer-php

I'm trying to upgrade an application (magento) but I can't proceed as per the following error

```
your PHP version (7.0.22) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0.2) doesnt satisfy requirements.
```

However there is **not** a `config->platform` setting in my composer.json. Viceversa, if I specify it or I add `ignore-platform-reqs`,s it works.

Tried to search also for the `7.0.2` or `platform` string over all the project but I can't see any can affect composer.

Any idea where the setting can be found?

Comment: Do you have configured platform in global `composer.json`? For example in `~/.composer/composer.json`.

Comment: thanks it was not in `~/.composer/config.json`!

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your php version on the `composer.json`

```
 "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.2"
    }
  },
```